# Google maps suddenly missing zoomControl, scaleControl and overviewMapControl

Tags: google-maps-api-3

All the Google maps on one of our sites suddenly (without any changes on our part) lost their zoom, scale and overviewmap controls:

http://www.suelos.cl/

the map in this link is being initialized using the 'initialize_map' function in:

http://www.suelos.cl/media/site/js/maps/mapa_main.js

These other maps don't work either:

www.suelos.cl/propiedades/terreno-en-colina/

www.suelos.cl/necesidades/busco-terreno-industrial-quilicura/

A possible datapoint: though "zoomControl" is one of the options listed in the reference, my IDE (pyCharm) marks it as 'unused', and if I inspect the Map instance in the Chrome console, it doesn't have a 'zoomControl' parameter, though it does have 'scaleControl' and 'overviewMapControl'.

Comment: This no longer seems to be the case, can you close this question if it is resolved? If not, please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had this recently, seems like the default was to turn it off.

I just explicitly added:

```
zoomControl: true
```